# How to create an zip archive that MS Windows 10 can extract

Tags: windows, zip, unzip

I'm trying to create a zip archive that a user on an MS Windows 10 laptop can extract. With only built-in MS Windows utilities.

But it is not clear to my how zip / unzip works on a MS Windows 10 machine. I only use Ubuntu. I tried already a couple of things

1. I created a zip archive on Ubuntu and found that the built-in MS Windows zip utility cannot extract it. It just reports that the archive is invalid. I can extract it using 7-zip but the users do not have 7-zip installed.
2. I created a zip archive on MS Windows using 7-zip and found that MS Windows also cannot extract it.
3. I tried to create a zip archive using right-click and then **Send to** and then **Compressed ( zipped ) folder** but this does not seem to do anything. I suppose this feature has not been implemented yet in MS Windows 10.

Is there another way to create a MS Windows 10 zip archive that MS Windows 10 can extract using only built-in MS Windows 10 utilities?

I sort of expected MS Windows 10 to support basic zip / unzip operations but this is not the case yet? Is it a requirement that we update user laptops with third party archive utility for example 7-zip to support basic zip / unzip?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are doing it incorrectly mate.. as you mentioned "you created a zip archive 
on MS Windows using 7-zip and found that MS Windows cannot extract it." it can't be, I have some files which are zipped on windows platform and I have my server running on Ubuntu machine I use those zip files for deployment.

Please check below things on your system, try it yourself.

1. Create a folder anywhere it could be on Desktop or in D Drive(example: **Desktop/MyFolder**)
2. Right click on MyFolder select->  **7-Zip**- -> select **Add to archive**.
3. you'll have new screen. now click on **Archive format** -> select **zip**.
4. You can configure rest of the option if you want like **Compression level, Encryption** etc.
5. Once you are done with configuration click **Ok** button.

Right on zip file which we just created and select 7-zip -> Extract to Myfolder/ Extract here.. you can select any of the option. it will also work on Ubuntu machine.

Hope this will work for you.

If this doesn't work the you can try WinRAR software available freely.

Cheers